# Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed

Tags: c#

```
try
{

    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand(); // connection string is correct, work great with other functions.

    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from BOOKS where ac_no='a10001'";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    int Ac_no = data.GetOrdinal("Ac_no");
    int Issn = data.GetOrdinal("Issn");
    int Isbn = data.GetOrdinal("Isbn");
    int Title = data.GetOrdinal("Title");
    int Author = data.GetOrdinal("Author");
    int Publisher = data.GetOrdinal("Publisher");
    int Edition = data.GetOrdinal("Edition");
    int Year = data.GetOrdinal("Year");
    int Price = data.GetOrdinal("Price");
    int Available = data.GetOrdinal("Available");
    int Rack_no = data.GetOrdinal("Rack_no");

    data.Read();

    /* works fine when label is used to display data */
    /* 

    lbl_Acno.Text = data.GetValue(Ac_no).ToString();
    lbl_Issn.Text = data.GetValue(Issn).ToString();
    lbl_Isbn.Text = data.GetValue(Isbn).ToString();
    lbl_Title.Text = data.GetValue(Title).ToString();
    lbl_Author.Text = data.GetValue(Author).ToString();
    lbl_Pub.Text = data.GetValue(Publisher).ToString();
    lbl_Edition.Text = data.GetValue(Edition).ToString();
    lbl_Book_Year.Text = data.GetValue(Year).ToString();

    */

    /* creates error when textboxes are used to display data */

    txt_acc_acno.Text = data.GetValue(Ac_no).ToString();
    txt_acc_issn.Text = data.GetValue(Issn).ToString();
    txt_acc_isbn.Text = data.GetValue(Isbn).ToString();
    txt_acc_title.Text = data.GetValue(Title).ToString();
    txt_acc_auth.Text = data.GetValue(Author).ToString();
    txt_acc_publisher.Text = data.GetValue(Publisher).ToString();
    txt_acc_edition.Text = data.GetValue(Edition).ToString();
    txt_acc_year.Text = data.GetValue(Year).ToString();
    txt_acc_price.Text = data.GetValue(Price).ToString();
    txt_acc_rack.Text = data.GetValue(Rack_no).ToString();

    con.Close();
}

catch (Exception e1)

{

    MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);

}
```

My problem is that, when i use the labels to display data then the data is displayed, but textboxes doesn't show data, instead an exception is generated "Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed."

the connection string is correct.

What's the correct method to display data (in textboxes) which is retrieved from database.

Comment: In the future, try to narrow down your problem to less code. The same problem would have occurred with a single textbox.

Comment: okay i'll take care of that...

Comment: Strongly suggest you change `e1.Message` to `e1.ToString()` to get all the exception details.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with what you use the data for, it happens when you try to read values from a data reader although it has already reported back that there is no more data.

The `Read` method returns a boolean that you can use to determine if there is any data:

```
if (data.Read()) {
  // there was a record, you can populate the form
} else {
  // no match for the ac_no, result was empty
}
```

Comment: if (data.Read()) {
  // populated the form here but the same problem
}

Comment: @Sunil Kumar: That's odd. On which line do you get the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call Read before you call GetOrdinal.

Comment: tried this

'if(data.Read())
{

int Ac_no = data.GetOrdinal("Ac_no");
txt_acc_acno.Text = data.GetValue(Ac_no).ToString();

}'

but the same problem.

Comment: No, you can call `GetOrdinal` before `Read`. See the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal.aspx